# Anime movie where two girls meet a giant rabbit creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I can't remember the name of this one movie where a young girl (6-8) and an older girl (Her sister, probably 12-14) are in a rural countryside area of Japan. The little girl finds this gigantic fluffy fat rabbit creature that is gray and has a white belly. She finds it by stumbling down a tunnel through two roots in a huge tree.

Then the older girl tries to find her little sister and when she can't, she goes to the creature and asks for help. It then calls its friend, a gigantic multi-legged fluffy cat-bus that tides the power lines to her little sister. They then grab some corn and give it to their sick mother.

The movie is in Japanese and it has an anime style, although it is a movie. I can't remember what this movie is called or the characters' names, but I believe that the director for the film is Hayao Miyazaki. Does anyone know what movie this is?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research. This is one of the most popular anime movies of all time. In fact it's literally the sixth result on google images if you search for "anime movie"

Comment: It is TOTORO! Oh, but yes, I have to agree with the lack of research comment. Next time, search google for "anime giant rabbit cat bus cute" before asking on any stackExchange website.  :)

Comment: @varun - even had the director's name in the question - just googling "Miyazaki" should have given the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*My Neighbour Totoro* (1988) most likely. Directed by Miyazaki.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Neighbor_Totoro):

> One day, **Mei discovers two small spirits who lead her into the hollow of a large camphor tree**. She befriends a larger spirit, which identifies itself by a series of roars that she interprets as "Totoro". She falls asleep atop Totoro, but when Satsuki finds her, she is on the ground. Despite many attempts, Mei is unable to show her family Totoro's tree. Tatsuo comforts her by telling her that Totoro will reveal himself when he wants to.
>
> One rainy night, the girls are waiting for Tatsuo's bus, which is late. Mei falls asleep on Satsuki's back, and Totoro appears beside them, allowing Satsuki to see him for the first time. Totoro has only a leaf on his head for protection against the rain, so Satsuki offers him the umbrella she had taken for her father. Totoro is delighted and gives her a bundle of nuts and seeds in return. **A giant, bus-shaped cat halts at the stop, and Totoro boards it and leaves.** Shortly after, Tatsuo's bus arrives.

Both the "giant rabbit" and the bus-cat can be seen in the trailer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've mentioned director's name, I could find the name of that movie. It is ***[Mei and the Kittenbus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0803038/)***.

From the [Ghibli Wiki](https://ghibli.fandom.com/wiki/Mei_and_the_Kittenbus):

> *Mei and the Kittenbus* (めいとこねこバス , *Mei to Konekobasu*) is a 13-minute animated film written and directed by Hayao Miyazaki and produced by Studio Ghibli and premiered in October 2002. It is the sequel to the 1988 film My Neighbor Totoro and is currently shown exclusively at the Saturn Theater, located at the basement of the Ghibli Museum in Mitaka, Tokyo. It has been considered the museum's most popular short film.
>
> The film tells the lighthearted story of Mei and her adventures with the Kittenbus, a child version of the Catbus. Totoro also makes a return appearance. As the sequel to a beloved classic, Miyazaki stated, “This piece was made specially for children.” This was possibly the last film of Hitoshi Takagi, the voice of Totoro, before his death and is the only direct sequel made to any Ghibli film. Joe Hisaishi returned to score the project.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note however that the OP already [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the film mentioned in [Jenayah's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237973/122024), _My Neighbour Totoro_, as the correct answer, as denoted by the green tick to the left of that answer. _Mei and the Kittenbus_ is apparently a sequel to that film, though.